Configuring port forwarding for my TP-Link router
First off, I have enabled and configured the built in OpenVPN Server feature

I have generated a certificate and exported a configuration (.ovpn) file.
This ovpn file however points to a local IP address 192.168.178.54 (not quite sure what this IP address is)
Now, I can connect with this configuration from my local network just fine. As soon as I try to access it from an outside network (even with my public ip address) it does not connect.
I have set up port triggering on port 1194. I have tried to set up Port fowarding (pretty sure this is necessary) on port 1194 but I can't seem to bind it to my router's ip address.
When trying to open port 1194 for 192.168.0.1 I get the error: The IP address cannot be the same with the LAN IP address. Please enter another one.
When trying to open port 1194 for 192.168.178.54 I get the error: The IP address and LAN IP address should be in the same subnet
I'm quite confused as how I'm meant to set up port forwarding for the open vpn server and what local ip address is assigned to the service

so the OpenVPN Server is built into the router, right? in that case, you likely do not need port forward rules, because the router is not passing the openVPN connections from the WAN into the LAN (though once a ovpn connection is established from the Internet to your router, it will likely forward traffic from the VPN to your local network. These instructions don't mention needing forwarding. https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/1239/ showing us a picture would help. also what do you mean by "open(ing) port 1194"?

192.168.0.1 is the gateway not the VPN unless your VPN is running in the gateway, of course your screenshot suggests, the VPN actually is an address in the 10.8.0.0 subnet for some reason. None of these addresses are routable from outside of your network obviously

TPLink has a feature called "Port triggering" https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/1522/. A picture of what exactly? I've followed it as per their instructions but connetctions from outside local network aren't working

You don’t have a screenshot of your port triggering rules.

It's set to triggering port 1194 mapped to external port 1194 with all protocol set (as broad as it gets). Here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/xErULJF.png

@Ramhound Yeah it makes sense it's assigned an IP in the subnet but I can't really figure out what IP is assigned and the guides I've found don't seem to mention this.

[Edit] your question instead of submitting temporary comments

It sounds to me that this router is behind another router/NAT, and 192.168.178.54 is its (the former's) WAN IP. Go to corresponding info page to confirm this. You probably don't need to configure port forwarding for this, since the service is likely listening on both the WAN side and the LAN side anyway. (It is pretty safe to assume that if you enable a VPN server on your router, you want it to be available on the Internet. And the problem here is that, its WAN side "isn't the Internet yet".)
If the "outer router" is managed by yourself, you may want to try either port forward there, or switch its operation mode into bridge mode. If it isn't also behind NAT (including CGNAT), it would probably get you to your goal.
EDIT: Make sure you disable / remove the port triggering rule from the TP-LINK router for port 1194 to avoid any potential "interference".

Yes! I have an ISP mandated modem that connects my internet via coax cable. I've set that to "bridge" mode already.

@VictorB So what WAN IP does the TP-LINK router have? Is it 192.168.178.54  (or some other 192.168.x.x) anyway? You should be able to find the information on some page of the admin portal. (I can't tell where exactly without the manual / model.) If it does, either the "modem router" isn't really working in bridge mode, or your ISP (ab)uses the 192.168/16 block for some sort of CGNAT. (There's not much you can do if it's the latter.)

@VictorB You may also try to access the admin portal of the "modem router" and see if its WAN IP is a public IP. If it is, see if you can port forward tcp port 1194 to 192.168.178.54 there, and then try to connect to the OpenVPN server with e.g. a phone via cellular network.
